# How do I test a function's logic but ignore the method calls?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a Rspec test for existing code that I've added some logic to that I want to ensure is working properly. I do not care about the returned values, just that the logic works on an object that I pass to it. For simplicity here is an example of very a basic function from within a class I have built:

```rb
def function_I_want_to_test(thing)
  if thing > 0
    function_a(thing)
  else
    function_b(thing)
  end
end
```

`function_a` and `function_b` already have spec tests, so I don't really care what the return values are, but both `function_a` and `function_b` make API calls which I feel would make the rspec test a lot more complicated for testing only the logic contained within `function_I_want_to_test`.

I've gone through this page (https://blog.codeship.com/unit-testing-in-ruby/) reviewing the unit testing approach, and the explanations make sense, but when attempting to use `allow` and `receive`, it appears that the function is still wanting to be called so I'm assuming I'm not utilizing the functions correctly.

Essentially I want to treat my code as such, and have it return something arbitrary so it doesn't even call the function.

```rb
def function_I_want_to_test(thing)
  if thing > 0
    pp "a"
  else
    pp "b"
  end
end
```

From my research, it appears the allow/expect is the way to go, but I'm assuming I'm not fully understanding the concept.

I guess the main question I have is, how does my rspec test know to "override" the functions (`function_a` and `function_b`) when testing `function_I_want_to_test`?

I know there are a few similar asked questions, but they didn't seem to answer how I was anticipating.

Comment: Something like `allow(obj).to receive_messages(function_a: 'a', function_b: 'b')` should work to replace those methods with stubs that return the given values.

Comment: Keyword: "Mocks"